# AR1021 Touch driver

Tags: touch

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion para pantallas tactiles. EL driver que estoy utilizando es el AR1021 para pantallas resistivas, y la plataforma de programacion es HArmony en mplab microchip.

La comunicación es por SPI, el micro es PIC32MZ2048ECH144. El caso es que tengo un programa dentro del main (**app_task() en harmony**) que me enciende y apaga un led ademas de dibujar objetos en la pantalla tactil, el problema viene cuando intento comunicar y activo el **system touch services de harmony** en ese momento el programa no se ejecuta.

Si comento una linea de codigo dentro de el sys_touch.c file  generado por harmony **SYS_TOUCH_Open(SYS_TOUCH_INDEX_0)**, el programa vuelve a ejecutarse pero las señales del SPI desaparecen. Parece que estan colisionando en algun punto o bien por utilizar los mismos puertos o por otro motivo que se me escapa.

Alguien sabria explicarme el porque?